# ZSS initial setup failing with invalid connection string

Tags: zumero

I am trying to get the Zumero for SQL Server working and I cannot get past running the test client. I get the below error

Connection string in `web.config` is

```
<settings temp_directory="C:\ProgramData\Zumero\ZSS Server\temp\" 
odbc_connection_string="DSN=krishna;User Id=syncadmin;Password=syncadmin;" 
license_key="<removed>" />
```

> The description for `Event ID 1` from source Zumero cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

```
Error -1 (mssql): {"diag":[{"SQL_DIAG_MESSAGE_TEXT":"[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open database \"ZumeroTest\" requested by the login. The login failed.","SQL_DIAG_NATIVE":4060,"SQL_DIAG_SQLSTATE":"42000"},{"SQL_DIAG_MESSAGE_TEXT":"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed","SQL_DIAG_NATIVE":0,"SQL_DIAG_SQLSTATE":"IM006"},{"SQL_DIAG_MESSAGE_TEXT":"[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute","SQL_DIAG_NATIVE":0,"SQL_DIAG_SQLSTATE":"01S00"}],"SQLRETURN":-1}
..\..\..\src\core\sg\sg_mssql.c:344
..\..\..\src\core\sg\sg_mssql.c:384
..\..\..\src\core\server\zum_db_mssql.c:2896
..\..\..\src\core\server\zum_respond.c:4454
..\..\..\src\servers\iis\main.cpp:1211
```

> The publisher has been disabled and its resource is not avaiable. This usually occurs when the publisher is in the process of being uninstalled or upgraded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either the SQL Server user doesn't have rights or the database doesn't exist.

You can use a DSN, but for troubleshooting purposes I recommend putting the connection details directly in the connection string for now. Once it's working you can migrate the settings back to a DSN if you like.

Looks like you're using SQL Server authentication. So the `odbc_connection_string` value should look like this:

```
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Database={database};Server={server.ad.domain.com};UID={sql_server_user};PWD={password};
```

The database must exist and the user specified must have appropriate read/write access to it.

(If you're setting minimum necessary permissions, you'll also want to make sure the user has `VIEW SERVER STATE` rights, [as described here](http://zumero.com/docs/zumero_for_sql_server_manager.html#permissions).)

Comment: Do we have to use ODBC? can't we use this connection string as is?

Comment: You can use a DSN, but it must use the (ODBC) Native Client 11 driver.

Answer (score 1):

While unrelated to your invalid connection string problem, the messages about  `The description for Event ID 1 [...]` and `The publisher has been disabled [...]` indicate that ZSS hasn't been correctly registered with the Windows Event Viewer.  Did you install the server by hand (from the .zip file) or using the installer?

You can fix those messages using the following command (which probably requires an admin prompt):

```
wevtutil im "PATH\TO\events.man" /rf:"PATH\TO\zumero_server.dll" /mf:"PATH\TO\zumero_server.dll"
```

where `PATH\TO` is the path where you extracted those files from the .zip.  If you used the installer then they should be located at: `%PROGRAMFILES%\Zumero\ZSS Server`

If you installed manually from the .zip then it's worth noting that the instructions had a subtle typo in that command which would cause it to fail.  That typo has been fixed in the past few days, but it may have caught you during your installation and caused this issue.